# How to update JSON array with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to update existing key with dynamic object of array how can I do that

```js
var groupData = [
  {
    "Logon": 0,
    "Logon": 1
  }, {
    "Logoff": 0
  }, {
    "Special Logon": 0
  }, {
    "Other System Events": 0
  }, {
    "System Integrity": 0
  }, {
    "Other Logon/Logoff Events": 0
  }, {
    "Security State Change": 0
  }, {
    "Audit Policy Change": 0
  }, {
    "Security Group Management": 0
  }
];

var key = logon;
var val = 10;
groupData[0].key = val;
```

Comment: actully i am getting key dynamically. i dont know which key it is in my array that why i want to update according to dynamic key

Comment: `{"Logon":0,"Logon":1}` ==> `{"Logon":1}`

Comment: Yes, I understood. `:)` Check answer. `:)`

Comment: where `logon` is defined ? (`var key = logon;`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `[]` notation as you need the value inside `key` and not the `key` itself:

```
groupData[0][key] = val;
```

Legend:

```
Object[key]; // Value of key index in Object.
Object.key;  // "key" index in Object.
```

Also, looks like you need to replace:

```
var key = "Logon";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var key = logon;
var val = 10;
groupData[0].key = val;
```

into

```
var key = "Logon";
var val = 10;
groupData[0][key] = val;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this

```
key = 'Logon';
val = 10;
groupData[0][key] = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
var key = 'Logon';
var val = 10;
groupData[0][key] = val;
```

Comment: Edited! what about now...?